# Deleting duplicate entries in 2 dimensional ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, hashset

I'm having trouble deleting multiple entries in my 2 dimensional ArrayList.
I have a Class named "Wall", which contains an ArrayList with Integers.
Now I've got an ArrayList of "Wall" and most of them contain the same Integers.
I changed my structure, so it's not possible anymore to use a HashSet to solve my problem.

It´s like:

```
public ArrayList<Wall> listOfWalls   = new ArrayList<Wall>();


  //The Class:


public class Wall {
private ArrayList<Squares> dots = new ArrayList<Squares>();
```

Each Square object contains a specific number.

Long story short:

My `ArrayList< ArrayList< Squares>>` contains about 40 of the same lists , but if you remove the doubles there are only 5 left. I want these 5 entries.

Specification:

Output before (shorten)(size: 6):

```
552
553
554

552
553
554

552
553
554

600
601
602

600
601
602

600
601
602
```

desired result (size: 2):

```
552
553
554

600
601
602
```

Comment: From the code you posted, it looks like you have an ArrayList<Wall>, but then in your last sentence, you say you have an ArrayList<ArrayList<Squares>>.  Which construct are you working with?

Comment: You have a list of instances of `Wall` and some of those walls are identical. You want to remove those. Is that correct? Why can't you use `HashSet`?

Comment: The ArrayList<ArrayList<Squares>> is within the Class Wall. First i worked with ArrayList<ArrayList<Squares>> listOfWalls but for reasons of enclosure i changed the structure to ArrayList<Wall> with an ArrayList<Squares> for each Object. Sorry, i´m editing it now

Comment: @Banthar: That is correct, but i don´t know how to check if the ArrayLists in the Class Wall are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to have duplicates, you have to use `Set` instead of `List`. For example:

```
Set<Wall> walls = new HashSet<>();
```

You will also have to define which Walls are identical by implementing `hashCode` and `equals` methods. In this case two walls are equal if they have equal set of squares:

```
class Wall {

    private final Set<Squares> dots = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return dots.equals(((Wall)obj).dots);
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return dots.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Two squares are equal if they have the same coordinates:

```
class Squares {
    int x,y;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Squares s = (Squares)obj;
        return x==s.x && y==s.y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 1000*y+x;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the order of elements in both collections is no longer defined. If your code depends on specific order you have to use `LinkedHashSet` instead of `HashSet`.

If you need list semantics, you can use set only temporary just to remove duplicates:

```
List<Wall> walls = ...
Set<Wall> uniqueWalls = new HashSet<>(walls);
walls = new ArrayList<>(uniqueWalls)
```

EDIT: Edited your equals-Method, you wrote x==s.y instead of x==s.x , now it´s working fine

Comment: The problem is that i need it as an ArrayList to have methods like get(). what do i do with the overwritten hashCode() Method? When using the code above it only checks if the next Wall is the same.

Comment: You do not call `hashCode` and `equals` directly. They are used by HashSet internally. If you still have problems show us more complete code sample - with example input and expected output. I'm not sure, if I understand the structure right.

Comment: When using the temporary solution , the size is 0. I think i´m doing something wrong.. I overwrite my equals() Method with my ArrayList<Squares> instead of the Set

Comment: I just checked if index 0 and index 1 of my listofWalls are the same. And indeed, both have the value -609055629. Nevertheless there are still duplicates , even with the temporary solution above.I keep working on it

Comment: Sorry for all the spam, interesting observation: listofWalls.get(0) and listofWalls.get(1) have the hashcode -609055629 but listOfWalls.get(0).equals(listOfWalls.get(1) is false. What´s going on here?